# Convergence of squared moment using higher order moment condition for non iid sequence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = 0$ and
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(|X_n|^{1+\eta}\right)}{n^\eta} \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$ for some $\eta > 0$. Letting $\bar{X}_n := X_n \mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n| \leq n\}}$, show that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E} \left(\bar{X}_n^2\right) \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

**Attempt**

When $\eta = 1$, the result is immediate. When $\eta < 1$, we can write
$$
\frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E} \left(\bar{X}_n^2\right) = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty 2 y \mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}_n| > y) \, \mathrm{d}y
$$
by a standard result on the representation of moments. Using integration by substitution and Markov's inequality, we get
$$
\frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty 2 y \mathbb{P}(|\bar{X}_n| > y) \, \mathrm{d}y \leq \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n 2 y \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > y) \, \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^1 2 n u \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > n u) \, \mathrm{d}u \leq 2 \left( \int_0^1 u^{-\eta}  \, \mathrm{d}u \right) \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(|X_n|^{1+\eta}\right)}{n^\eta}
$$
and hence we are finished.

I'm not sure how to deal with the $\eta > 1$ case though, I somehow thought this would be the easiest but the math just won't budge. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false if $\eta >1$.  Let $(Y_n)$ be i.i.d. taking values $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac 1  2$ each. Let $X_n =\sqrt n Y_n$. You can easily check that this is  a counter-example.

Comment: @Lundborg Sorry. I misread the definition. I have edited my answer.